# Git clone from one server to another without superuser access

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

I want to setup a git environment for my coworkers and me between the dev server and the prod server (and later between local machines and the dev server as well). Installed git on prod, init, everything is fine.

Now I want to `git clone` the prod into the dev, to then be able to push validated features to prod. I tried to do so with

```
git clone ssh://sshUser@111.11.11.111:1234/path/to/git/repos/
```

The issue is, that user is not a superuser and has no access to that path. So of course it fails. I can't connect in root because `PermitRootLogin no`. So I thought of 2 possibilities :

- Change `PermitRootLogin no` to `PermitRootLogin without-password` and use a ssh key to connect as root. I guess it would work.
- Create another superuser to keep root deactivated and do the exact same thing with that new user (a little more secure maybe).

But I'm not sure whether it's the right way to go or if I have another option I didn't think of / found info about.

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having application files on your production system that require `root` access is not a good idea in the first place, and further opening up your `root` account in the way you describe is an absolute no-no. A good (i.e., secure) approach is this:

- Make a group `myapp` and a user `myappadm`.
- Everything related to your application (i.e. `/path/to/git/repos/`) should be `chown`'ed to `myappadm:myapp`.
- Everything should be writable by `myappadm` but only readable by `myapp`.
- Things like your webserver can go into group `myapp`.

(Of course, if you already have a group like `myapp` and only have `root` instead of `myappadm` then you can keep that group and just chown everything to `myappadm` instead of `root`.)

That done, you will clone from `ssh://myappadm@...` and all will be fine. People who have access to `myappadm` will no longer be able to take over the whole machine, and so on.

Comment: That's very nicely explained, thanks. That clarified things that were cloudy in my head. In fact, a user already had the rights exactly set like that, just not our regular ssh user but the one we use for ftp... Everything is fine now. Thanks !

Comment: Cheers, glad it was helpful.